# Get string of type Mixed in sencha touch

Tags: touch, extjs, textfield

might be a stupid question but I seem to be confused. Im pretty new to sencha touch. Ive got a textfield and all I want to do is save the value of the textfield. Ive put a change listener on the field and want to listen to the "newValue" which is type "Mixed". How would I get the real String which is in the textfield ? Should be easy - I guess? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the value you are getting will be of String type, you can check that by using this method

```
if(Ext.isString(value)) {
   alert('string');
} else {
   alert('something else');
}
```

actually Mixed is not a data type of javascript, its just notation used in documentation of sencha to denote a combination of the single types (like Boolean, String, Number, Array, Object, etc.).

Mixed type is normally used to define a return value or a parameter that can pass anything, so a class who wants extend textfield can return boolean in getValue function, so the type of return value is not fixed, and can be changed by subclasses

**Reference:**

http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-58718.html